# Making overlay text visible on a "chaotic" background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, photoshop-effects, overlay

[image]

I am trying to create a fullscreen map with some overlaying menus above it as you can see in the screenshot above. I have tried to make the overlaying text visible by applying an inner glow on a fullscreen, no-fill rectangle shape that is on top of the map image layer. However as you can see, it's not really doing a good or a neat job when it comes to presenting the image visually.

Any ideas or tips on how I could get the text above to show up against the map background. The text should preferably remain white.

If you need more information, do let me know. Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add a small drop shadow (a pixel maybe two) with a zero distance setting.

Comment: You can use a little dark color for map so that white text can be visible over it. Or use drop shadow effect in text layers.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider the design. The vignette of the map does nothing but add confusion and make readability difficult. Frame the map and your UI rather than floating everything.

Answer (score 0):

Add a small drop shadow with a zero distance setting.

I used a setting of Opacity 100%, Distance 0, Spread 0, Size 5 on the text...

[image]

Also, I would suggest that you use a different colour to identify your interface elements (I notice you've used red for the place markers, so why not use one of the banks standard colours for your icons on the very right?).

Comment: are you all set with this project? It will be good to know what you ended up doing.

Comment: @ACEkin: I think you posted your comment against the wrong person.

Comment: Ooops! My presidential candidate moment ;-) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the requirements or limitations you set for the design, so what I am about to suggest may or may not work for you.

1. Do not use white text for the menus on the right
2. I chose red but you can substitute black with similar results
3. Use a more robust font, I have two variants, Berlin Sans FB and Berlin Sans FB Demi for slightly bolder rendering
4. Use an outer glow with white color, where the background is light it will not interfere, but where it is dark it will help separate the text

You will find examples of each in the image below, normal font plain and with white outer glow and the same with demi font. I think a medium weight font is ideal for this work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment @ACEkin. Will try out your suggestion and see how it goes.